# fetching json response instead of php in ios

Tags: php, ios, json

I am currently using a really inefficient way of retrieving data from mysql. I wrote very small script to test the functionality (I am very new to ios development). Here is the end of the script which is my main concern:

```
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($articles));
fclose($fp);
```

so i change my results from query to json and then write it to file with .json so that I read it using objective-c. it works but I can see this being a problem (every time creating files and deleting them when querying the database). This is the ios end of things:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://link/results.json"]];

    NSError* error;

    eventsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&error];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

How can I make my php script return json instead of writing it to file and then just read that with objective-c? I am interested in obj-c part so please emphasise as much as possible.

greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Does echo json_encode($articles); help you?

Comment: knowing PHP that would just print it on the screen right? so am interested in the part after which is reading that data using iphone api

Comment: Script will return json string. If you run it in browser it will return string on screen. If you make url request from iOS device to script, you will get exactly what you want.